# repmgrd automatic node rejoin

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

I have installed repmgr5 onto Postgresql 12 database with repmgrd with 2 nodes one is primary and the other one is standby.

When I tried to make postgresql to failover automatically through disabling postgresql service on primary node. Switchover happens successfully but old primary stopped following new primary and replication between 2 nodes is broken as well.

Is there any way to automatically rejoin old primary node to new primary node ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try node rejoin on the old primary. Please ensure to stop the postgre service before running the rejoin.